# Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'

Tags: java, android-studio-3.0

I updated to Android Studio 3.0.1 and have this error in my console:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :libraries:Jumble:generateDebugSources, :libraries:Jumble:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :libraries:Jumble:mockableAndroidJar]

Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :libraries:Jumble.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot choose between the following configurations of project :libraries:Jumble:
          - debugRuntimeElements
          - releaseRuntimeElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but no value provided.
              - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but no value provided.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but no value provided.
              - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but no value provided.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
```

What caused this problem after the update?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed problem!
My application did not have the `build.gradle` file in the root folder.
I added the below and the problem has been solved:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: isn't helpful for this problem

Comment: Do you mind pointing out what exactly you added?

Answer (score 1):

If you have any module library, which should have the same build type mentioned in your app project also.
I have added this buildTypes in library too because the same as mentioned types in your app.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug{}
        uat{}
    }
```

It works for me.